# Qt Transparent Background Widget

Tags: qt, transparent

I want to make my own custom tooltip. So I create a class like below.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QWidget.__init__(self, parent, Qt.ToolTip)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    rect = self.rect()

    path = QPainterPath()
    path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill)
    path.addRoundedRect(rect.adjusted(self.PADDING+self.ARROW_DEPTH, self.PADDING, -self.PADDING, -self.PADDING), self.ARROW_DEPTH, self.ARROW_DEPTH)
    path.moveTo(self.PADDING, rect.height()/2)
    path.lineTo(self.PADDING+self.ARROW_DEPTH, rect.height()/2 - self.ARROW_OFFSET)
    path.lineTo(self.PADDING+self.ARROW_DEPTH, rect.height()/2 + self.ARROW_OFFSET)
    path.lineTo(self.PADDING, rect.height()/2)

    painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
    painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
    painter.drawPath(path)
```

But the result is...

[image: Custom tooltip]

How can I make the black region be transparent?

## SOLUTION

```
QWidget.__init__(self, parent, Qt.ToolTip)
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

I add a line **self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)**, and it works.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: change     `path.addRoundedRect(rect.adjusted(self.PADDING+self.ARROW_DEPTH, self.PADDING, -self.PADDING, -self.PADDING), self.ARROW_DEPTH, self.ARROW_DEPTH)` to `path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(rect.adjusted(self.PADDING + self.ARROW_DEPTH,
                                          self.PADDING, -self.PADDING, -self.PADDING)),
                            self.ARROW_DEPTH, self.ARROW_DEPTH)`

Comment: @eyllanesc I work on Win7. and I tried QRectF as you mentioned, but it does not work on my case.

Comment: Did you consider using a [mask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setMask) especially since the visible part of your widget doesn't have the standard rectangular form?